# Multi column lookup field in WSS 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0

We are using WSS 3.0 and have a list that has four fields that we would like to use as the basis for a new list.  Is there an option in WSS 3.0 that would allow for me to do this?  Any ideas on how we can accomplish this?

Comment: do you want relationships to be preserved?

Comment: Yes, in a perfect world we would like to have the four fields to be linked in the new list so that they would auto-populate.  I have seen this for newer versions as "enforced relationships", but I don't know if this is possible in WSS 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSS 3.0 doesn't offer hierarchical look-ups or Connected look-ups. But, still you can implement such look-ups using one of the following two ways:

1. You could really use the jQuery library by Marc D Anderson, [see example](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/a-jquery-library-for-sharepoint-web-services-wss-3-0-and-moss-part-3-the-spdisplayrelatedinfo-function.aspx)
2. [Custom Connected Look-up from CodePlex](http://cl.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I used the JQuery library and it works great!

Comment: Great to know that! Mark it as answer if it has helped :-)